# Git push files to different repository

Tags: git, github

I want to push to two repositories. However, the second repository does not contain the same files as the first repository. When trying to push to the second I get:

```
error: failed to push some refs to
Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally.
```

This is because of different files on the two repositories. This is fixed if I pull from the second repository into the first. However, these repositories (for example) have two completely different README.md files and this pull introduces merge conflicts and will break everything if pushed.

I need a way to push the single file to the second repository without the need to have the same files in the two repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the second repository on a different folder, and then add your file and commit it

Comment: Not possible. The files must be in one folder.

Comment: Copy the file(s) by hand

Comment: I need to do this and then make it an automated process using web hooks. So manually does not work for me.

Comment: Automated merges is a whole new issue

Comment: Yes. I agree. However, making the above scenario work I will have a successful strategy to apply to the automatic process.